# Explanation of "Boards" in Pins R-Package

Tags: r, pins

I am mainly interested in the "Boards" created using any of the `board_` variants from the `pins` package. When you do so, I don't "see" a board (or at least a folder representing a board, maybe like how a .git folder would contain all the commit hashes for a project). Even when you toggle hidden folders in the View tab you don't see anything. Are Boards effectively generated temporarily for a given session (Not referring to `board_temp` here)?

Through the testing i've done so far, I can create a board in my session and then generate Pins which you do see the folders for (versioned or not). The main impetus of my interest is how do you know a board exists within a given directory? Even if there are folders with the name of your pins, how do you distinguish that as a "Board" vs some random directory with some sub-folders?

And this relates to how you access a board you generated previously:

- Create a board for a given data source I want to track over time
- Do work with it in session 1
- Close that session
- Open session 2 where I want to add a new version of that previous pin

Is there an actual "Board" I am accessing for my pin?